# Redirect to a sub folder using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I moved a website over to a sub folder and I added a htaccess file to the root of the site. For some reason it is not redirecting to the subfolder. below is my code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks


#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /public_html/corp/
```

i also tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks


#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /corp/
```

The site is actually in a folder called /corp/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 DirectoryIndex /corp/index.php
```

or

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ corp [L,R=301]
```

Are other alternative methods as well.

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteBase` only specifies the base for every `RewriteRule`. If you don't have a `RewriteRule`, there won't be a rewrite.