# How to remove subfolder from url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I moved my site to a subfolder called /corp/. So to get to the site you type in

```
mywebsite.com/corp/index.php
```

I would like to remove the /corp/ so it looks like

```
mywebsite.com/index.php
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Isn't this the same as your [other (now answered) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497607/redirect-to-a-sub-folder-using-htaccess)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your UserDir in your APACHE settings to the appropriate folder. IE if right now your UserDir is `UserDir /public_html` change it to `UserDir /public_html/corp`

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html for more info

Comment: I have cpanel, is there away to modify that using cpanel ?? Otherwise I have no clue how to change that.